# Page break on print property (orphan) not supported in FireFox

Tags: css, firefox

I'm using the `orphan` property to add a page break on print if the data is large it is working in chrome and IE but no support of it in **FireFox**.

```
docprint.document.write('</head>
             <body onLoad="self.print()">
              <fieldset class="result tbl" style="border-width: 0 0 0 !important;">
               <div class="table report_data" style="width:100% !important;
                          padding-left:4px !important;
                          padding-Right:5px !important;orphans:7;">');
---------------------------------------------------------^^this is not supported in Firefox
```

Anybody know of workaround for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Few property cannot be supported by firefox....

[Check this site...](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/orphans) and [this...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/orphans)

Comment: i know its not supported thats why i asked for the work around `:)`